# Why doctest can't find functions defined on the same file when executed with tesfile?

Tags: python, doctest

I have a package `mypackage` where I have `foo.py`

```
# mypackage/foo.py
def foo():
    """
    >>> 1
    1

    >>> bar()
    'bar'
    """
    pass

def bar():
    return "bar"
```

If I run `python -m doctest mypackage/foo.py` it works like a charm, but. If I create a test file with ...

```
import doctest 
doctest.testfile("foo.py", package="mypackage")
```

... in the same folder as mypackage, and run this file, it fails with

```
**********************************************************************
File "/Users/gecko/code/python/doctesttest/mypackage/foo.py", line 6, in foo.py
Failed example:
    bar()
Exception raised:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/gecko/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/doctest.py", line 1329, in __run
        exec(compile(example.source, filename, "single",
      File "<doctest foo.py[1]>", line 1, in <module>
        bar()
    NameError: name 'bar' is not defined
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of   2 in foo.py
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
➜  doctesttest
```

My question is why, and how to fix it?

Comment: In your example, [`python -m doctest` imports the module and then uses `doctest.testmod`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/fc40b3020cf3c869833fd5d3720cf9768fe3bb46/Lib/doctest.py#L2779-L2787), it does not use `doctest.testfile`.  So perhaps you should use `testmod` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure to import `bar` when running doctest. For example, in the same directory I have `example.txt` and `foo.py`

```
# example.txt
>>> from foo import bar

>>> 1
1

>>> bar()
'bar'
```

```
# foo.py
def bar():
    return "bar"
```

now the python interpreter will show 0 failed tested lines.

```
import doctest
doctest.testfile('example.txt')
>>> TestResults(failed=0, attempted=3)
```

However, if I omit the line `>>> from foo import bar`, I'll get the following error

```
>>> doctest.testfile('example.txt')
**********************************************************************
File "./example.txt", line 6, in example.txt
Failed example:
    bar()
Exception raised:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/doctest.py", line 1329, in __run
        exec(compile(example.source, filename, "single",
      File "<doctest example.txt[1]>", line 1, in <module>
        bar()
    NameError: name 'bar' is not defined
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of   2 in example.txt
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
TestResults(failed=1, attempted=2)
```

Comment: It's weird have to import a function from the same module, isn't this a bug?

Comment: BTW `doctest.testmod()` works like a charm this may be something in testfile implementation

Comment: when you ran it from the cli it actually imports the module. Though using the `>>>` is like using a Python session, so `bar` must be "defined" or in this case imported from mypackage, a more detailed explanation can be found on the [docs](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/doctest.html#simple-usage-checking-examples-in-docstrings)

Comment: Well, now this make some sense. Since testfile would be used in non python files